# mysql how to select maximum value of a column as another column in the resultset

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is like this

```
ID  VALUE  
1   4  
2   6  
3   12
```

I want to get an output in this format in mysql, could you provide me with
an appropriate sql for the same

```
ID   VALUE  MAX_VALUE DIV_BY_MAX_VALUE  
1       4     12         0.33  
2       6     12         0.5   
3      12     12         1.0
```

Answer (score 5):

You would join in the maximum and do the division:

```
select t.*, x.maxvalue, t.value / x.maxvalue
from t cross join
     (select max(value) as maxvalue from t) x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select id,value,(select max(value) from mytable) as max_value, value/(select max(value) from mytable) as division from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @max_value = (select max(value) from mytable);
Select id, value, @max_value, value/@max_value as div_by_max from mytable;
COMMIT;
```